# Related Categories

Tags: categories

Is there anyway to relate a category tag pair to a entries tag pair? I have this code below and I am trying to get the 'long_head' custom category name to relate to the entries being outputted above it. So if the entry above had a category of 'BEANS' I would like the 'long_head' to be the long head from the category 'BEANS'.

Any help would be great.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="services" limit="1"}
<div id="page">
    <h2>{title}</h2>
    <div>
        {service_text}
    </div>
</div>
<!-- // page -->
{/exp:channel:entries}

<div id="nxtBack">
    <p><a href="{site_url}" title="Back to Home Page">&larr; Back to Home Page</a></p>
</div>

<div id="rel-work">
    {exp:channel:categories style="none"}
    <h2>{long_head} Projects</h2>
    {/exp:channel:categories}
    <ul>
        {exp:channel:entries channel="work" limit="20" status="New|Open" related_categories_mode="yes" custom_fields="yes"}
        {if no_results}
            <p class="alert">There are currently no related projects to this service in our online portfolio.</p>
        {/if}
        <li>
            <a href="{title_permalink="work/view"}" title="{title}"><img src="{project_th}" alt="{title}" />{if status == "New"}<img src="/_/img/new-work.png" class="new" alt="NEW Project - {title}" />{/if}</a>
            <h3><a href="{title_permalink="work/view"}" title="">{title}</a></h3>
            <h4>{categories backspace="2"}<a href="{path="work"}" title="">{category_name}</a> / {/categories}</h4>
            <p>{project_excerpt}</p>
        </li>
        {/exp:channel:entries}
    </ul>
    <p><a href="{site_url}work" title="View all work">View all work &rarr;</a></p>
</div>
<!-- // rel-work -->
```

Comment: Can you, please, mark the right answer?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're just outputting a single channel entry at the top, you can just enclose the category section inside the `channel:entries` loop:

```
{exp:channel:entries 
    channel='services' 
    limit='1'
    disable='pagination|member_data'
}
    <div id="page">
        <h2>{title}</h2>
        <div>
            {service_text}
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- // page -->

    <div id="nxtBack">
        <p><a href="{site_url}" title="Back to Home Page">&larr; Back to Home Page</a></p>
    </div>

    <div id="rel-work">
        {categories}
            <h2>{long_head} Projects</h2>
        {/categories}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: I see thanks I will give that ago ... Can that work in practice the other way round. I often wonder if you can enclose entry tag pairs inside category tag pairs?

Comment: That worked fine many thanks for your input.

Comment: You can with [NSM Categories](http://ee-garage.com/nsm-categories). Please mark my question as the answer, thanks.